# SUM and ROUND? based on sum comparison to another field

Tags: sql, sum, case, rounding

I am attempting to get a sum of a few fields to now round up to the next multiple of an integer in another column.

An example would be: The sum of these select columns is 15. The column I want to compare it to is 13. I would like for the SUM to then round up to 26, because it is the next multiple of 13 that covers the SUM. The sum, and comparative column, will be different for each Item, so I am hoping to find a SQL that can make this calculation based on the Item/Loc.

I have been able to get the SUM to work, but am not sure how to connect this number to the comparison field/table, and then rounding it up. Any help would be greatly appreciated, either how to connect the two fields from separate tables, or how to round to specific multiples. Either will get me closer to my final goal.

My current SQL looks like

```
select s.Item,
       s.Loc, 
       p.MinDRPQty,
       p.IncDRPQty,
       SUM (s.OH + s.UDC_ActualIT + s.UDC_CommitIT 
                 - s.UDC_AllCustOrd  s.UDC_ADJ_AvgDailyDmd
                 *(p.DRPCovDur/1440) - s.UDC_SafetyStock)
       as NetNeed 
from SKU s,
     SKUPlanningParam p 
where s.Item = p.Item and s.Loc = p.Loc 
group by s.Item, s.Loc, p.MinDRPQty, p.IncDRPQty
```

MinDRPQty is the number I am comparing to SUM (NetNeed)

That part works, in getting the SUM. I assume I need to use CASE, or IF to get it to work, but I am not well versed in using those.

Based on the assistance of Daileyo, I have gotten closer to what I am looking for. My problem now is that the script doesn't want to work when using more than one table. I need both tables to gather all my data, and I get errors when doing so.

My revised script looks like

```
SELECT 
   Item, Loc,
   orig as "NetNeed", 
   mult as "MinDRPQty", 
   (orig/mult) as "multiples_needed", 
   CASE 
      WHEN (orig/mult) <= 1 THEN mult  --always use next multiple if sum is < than multiplier
      ELSE CEIL(orig/mult)*mult --determine appropriate multiple, convert to int, and multiply
   END AS "ExpectedOrder"
 FROM
 (
     SELECT s.Item, s.Loc, SUM(s.OH + s.UDC_ActualIT + s.UDC_CommitIT - s.UDC_AllCustOrd - s.UDC_ADJ_AvgDailyDmd*(p.DRPCovDur/1440) - s.UDC_SafetyStock) as orig, p.MinDRPQty as mult  
     FROM  SKU s, group by s.Item, s.Loc
 )
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you need a few steps to occur in the query

1. Sum up a series of columns
2. Determine multiples for a value within another column
3. Adjust your returned sum UP to the next value that is a valid multiple in step two.

You have already got step 1 going, so lets work on steps 2 and 3.

Assuming that you do indeed need to always round up to the next multiple, then first check in your [case statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) will be to handle whether or not your sum is greater than or less than the column you are checking against.  If it is less, then your result will always be that column times 2.
Your else would be to handle what multiple needs to be used.

I believe the following demonstrates a working example of what you are wanting.   I am using the [CEIL](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/ceil.php) function from Oracle, which is basically just rounding the value Up, unless it is a whole number.

If you are wanting to work with fractional numbers, it changes things a bit.  Also, if you are actually only wanting round up to the next multiple if your sum is greater than your check column... then you will need to adjust the first part of the case statement.

This example is assuming you are using Oracle.

```
 SELECT 
   orig as "summed_value", 
   mult as "multiplier", 
   (orig/mult) as "multiples_needed", 
   CASE 
      WHEN (orig/mult) <= 1 THEN mult*2  --always use next multiple if sum is < than multiplier
      ELSE CEIL(orig/mult)*mult --determine appropriate multiple, convert to int, and multiply
   END AS "result"
 FROM
 (
     SELECT SUM(1 + 5 + 2 +100) as orig, 17 as mult  FROM DUAL
 );
```

**UPDATE**
Based on the additional information, I'd say the simplest thing to do would be treat your existing query as an [inline view](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Inline_view), and then do the calculation work from there:

```
    SELECT 
     result_item
     ,result_location
     ,result_Min
     ,result_Inc
     ,result_NetNeed
     ,CASE 
        WHEN (result_NetNeed/resultMin) <= 1 THEN result_Min --use existing multiplier if  sum is less than multiplier
        ELSE CEIL(result_NetNeed/resultMin)*result_Min --determine appropriate multiple, convert to int, and multiply 
     END
     FROM
     (
       select 
       s.Item as result_item, 
       s.Loc as result_location, 
       p.MinDRPQty as result_Min, 
       p.IncDRPQty as result_Inc, 
       SUM (s.OH + s.UDC_ActualIT + s.UDC_CommitIT - s.UDC_AllCustOrd - s.UDC_ADJ_AvgDailyDmd*  (p.DRPCovDur/1440) - s.UDC_SafetyStock) as result_NetNeed 
       from SKU s, SKUPlanningParam p 
       where s.Item = p.Item and s.Loc = p.Loc group by s.Item, s.Loc, p.MinDRPQty, p.IncDRPQty
     );
```

I can't test the SQL, so forgive me if there are any typos... the logic should be largely correct though.

As an aside, I would consider using JOIN rather than doing a query on multiple tables.  There is nothing directly wrong with doing the query on two tables... but in my opinion it makes the intent a bit more readable.  Also it can have an improvement on query performance.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It has helped a good deal. I am having trouble, however, when I attempt to add my table and column names, particularly because I am using two different tables to gather all of my data. Just using one table, your example works perfectly. But I get errors when using both tables.

Comment: It would be difficult to help with modifying without knowing some additional information. Are you already getting your compare value in your existing query (i.e. you your existing query returns s.Item, s.Loc, and NetNeeded... are any of these your compare value?)  If not, can you get that value as part of your result set with a JOIN or anything?  If you can get your compare value as part of your existing query... then you should be able to treat your existing query as an inline view and then do the multiplier case-work on the inline view.

Comment: My existing query does get the compare value. Not the one that I posted, but I do have one that does get that value.MinDRPQty is value I am comparing to the SUM (NetNeed).

Comment: select s.Item, s.Loc, p.MinDRPQty, p.IncDRPQty, SUM (s.OH + s.UDC_ActualIT + s.UDC_CommitIT - s.UDC_AllCustOrd - s.UDC_ADJ_AvgDailyDmd*(p.DRPCovDur/1440) - s.UDC_SafetyStock) as NetNeed from SKU s, SKUPlanningParam p where s.Item = p.Item and s.Loc = p.Loc group by s.Item, s.Loc, p.MinDRPQty, p.IncDRPQty

Comment: Thank you so much for your help with this. It works wonderfully, and looks so much better than mine. I appreciate the suggestion on the JOIN as well. That will be my next learning.